# How to print all the values in between the two slider range selected, not just those two values?

Tags: r, shiny, slider, range

I'm trying to use a slider range which will dynamically change the values on the X-axis on my ggplot. I can get the min and max (two values selected) to display but need the whole range between these selected values to print.

UI

```
sliderTextInput("slider", strong("Year and Quarter"),
choices = unique(mydata2$PERIOD),
selected = c(("2011-Q4"),("2017-Q3")),
dragRange=TRUE
```

Server

Function for the graph

`````
shovegraphintofunction1 = function(input) {
CCGdata = mydata2[(mydata2$GEOG_NAME==input$GEOG_NAME),]
CCGrefdata = mydata2[(mydata2$GEOGRAPHYref==input$GEOGRAPHYref),]
CCGdata = mydata2[(mydata2$PERIOD==input$slider),]
CCGrefdata = mydata2[(mydata2$PERIOD==input$slider),]

date_start <- as.character(input$slider[1])
date_end <- as.character(input$slider[2])


lineplot = ggplot(data=CCGdata, mapping=aes(x=PERIOD, y=statistic, group=statistic.name)) +
geom_line(aes(color=statistic.name, size=statistic.name))+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,10), labels=c("0%", "10%", "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "90%", "100%"), limits=c(0, 100))+ 
scale_x_discrete(breaks=CCGdata$PERIOD, labels=CCGdata$PERIOD, limits=c(input$slider[1], input$slider[2]))

    }
````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
mydata2 %>%
  filter(between(PERIOD ,date_start, date_end)) %>%
  select(PERIODE) %>%
  unique()
```

of course you need first to convert `date_start` and `date_end` in date format. I canot go further the date conversion because you don't provide any date format.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried but get the error Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data. Not sure how to get around this.